# How to pass data from filter to action in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

app/filters.php

```
App::before(function($request){

    $sys_message = DB::table('u_message')->where('uid','=','0')->get();
});
```

app/routes.php

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return View::make('index');
});
```

Now, I want to use `$sys_message` in view the index page, how to change the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can share it, available in all view;

```
App::before(function($request){

    $sys_message = DB::table('u_message')->where('uid','=','0')->get();

     View::share('sys_message',  $sys_message);
});
```